# How to get the closest id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

In a iOS APP, There is a webView contains many text lines. By now, I use javascript to detect which text is clicked by user. But because of big line height and line break(blank space), sometimes the text is not clicked right.

If click on position of green dot, text 1 can be detected, the 2 and the 4 can not by clicking on blue dot and red dot.

Is it possible to get the closest id even click on blank? and if there are two text near the clicking position, get the closest.

Thanks.

[image]

```
    <span id='1'>This is text</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id='2'>This is text 2</span>
    <br>
    <p>
    <span id='3'>This is text 3</span>
    <br>
    <span id='4'>This is text 4</span>
```

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate suggestion. Here, OP want the "closest" `id` from the user `touch` event... It's not the same thing as jQuery `.closest()` which will find the first `id` seaking up the parent element.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette yes, get the closest `id` from the user touch.

Comment: I work on it... But it isn't an easy one. Have to get x/y position clicked and compare to all elements positions to find the nearest. ;) +1 for your question.

Comment: I made something for you... I took it from the **math** side. ;)

Comment: @CommercialSuicide Of course, you don't need jQuery to do that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Comment: @Rob, it's a matter of taste to use jQuery or pure Javascript. Sure, we can implement jQuery code with pure Javascript, jQuery is just a library for more comfortable coding.

Comment: @CommercialSuicide Yes but I'm just suggesting that one does not need jQuery to do the same thing if one is not using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible you would want to put the text inside of another div tag that has some padding on it that can be clicked. An example is at [this weave](http://liveweave.com/7zkY2Y). The amount of padding can be adjusted by simply changing the padding for .holder in the CSS. I hope this is the type of solution you are looking for...

Comment: This method is compatible with all devices. I used jQuery, which I assumed was OK. If you want a vanilla JavaScript version, I could make that also...

Comment: It works great but problem is that I have to set the id first. How to do that if  number of id is unknown?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question. What do you mean by 'number of ID  is unknown?' What do you mean by setting 'the ID first?' Whatever the problem is, I'll fix it for you, I just don't quite understand your question.

Comment: In the example you refer to, need to set `$('#containerOne, #containerTwo, #containerThree, #containerFour').click(function ()` first. I now use `$('[id]').click(function ()`, and it works. Thx.

Comment: Sorry, I tested the example deeply, I found it works if blank is inside the `div`, when I try to use `span` and put them  together like normal text with a big line height, it failed.

Comment: If it helps, I also made a [new version](http://liveweave.com/Q1ppNV) that operates by looking for a click by class name, so it is certainly less typing.

Comment: Sorry, the codes don't fit my need. You can try to replace all the `div` with `span`, then add 3 or 6 `<br>` between the containers(not in span) so that there is enough blank space to click. You may know what I need. Thx.

Comment: Ok jdleung. It does seem like your question has been answered before, however, so I apologize for not creating a new version.

Answer (score 0):

I got interested in the math problem of your question... And I got something working.

The principle is to have the position (x/y) of all element targeted.
That is the top-left corner...

You have to care about the height and width too to make the right distance calculations.

The **real distance** between a click (x/y) from user and a corner of the **closest element** will be the **shortest hypothenuse**.

This said... Here is the thing in the below snippet:

```js
console.clear();

var positions =[];
var idElements = $("[id]");

// Get position and dimension of all target elements.
for(i=0;i<idElements.length;i++){
  positions.push({
    x: idElements.eq(i).offset().left,
    y: idElements.eq(i).offset().top,
    h: idElements.eq(i).height(),
    w: idElements.eq(i).width()
  });
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(positions));

// On click... Find the nearest.
$(document).on("click",function(e){
  var x = e.pageX;
  var y = e.pageY;
  console.log("User clicked at "+x+"/"+y);

  // Reset results, if any...
  idElements.css({
    "background-color":"initial",
    "border":"initial"
  })

  // Find the closest element.
  var distances = [];
  for(i=0;i<positions.length;i++){

    // Evaluate distance on X axis
    if(x>positions[i].x){
      // Click occured on the right of the left position
      // So get the distance from right side...
      distanceX = x - (positions[i].x + positions[i].w);
    }else{
      // Click occured on the left of the left position
      distanceX = x - positions[i].x;
    }

    // Evaluate distance on Y axis
    if(y>positions[i].y){
      // Click occured below of the top position
      // So get the distance from bottom side...
      distanceY = y - (positions[i].y + positions[i].h);
    }else{
      // Click occured on the left of the left position
      distanceY = y - positions[i].y;
    }

    // Hypothenuse
    hyp = Math.sqrt( (distanceX*distanceX)+(distanceY*distanceY) );

    distances.push({
      dx: distanceX,
      dy: distanceY,
      hyp: hyp
    });
  }

  console.log(JSON.stringify(distances));

  // The real distance will ALWAY be the hypothenuse of the x/y distances calculated above.
  // Have to find the shortest.

  var shortestHyp=100000;
  var shortestHyp_index=0;
  for(i=0;i<distances.length;i++){

    //console.log(distances[i].hyp);

    if(distances[i].hyp < shortestHyp){
      //console.log("shorter");
      shortestHyp = distances[i].hyp;
      shortestHyp_index = i;
    }
  }
  console.log(shortestHyp_index);


  // Show result
  idElements.eq(shortestHyp_index).css({
    "background-color":"yellow",
    "border":"1px solid blue"
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id='1'>This is text</span> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id='2'>This is text 2</span>
<br>
<p>
  <span id='3'>This is text 3</span>
  <br>
  <span id='4'>This is text 4</span>
</p>
```

Also in [**CodePen**](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/przwGZ?editors=1011).

Comment: The answer was canceled after my deep test. It doesn't works. I will take a look of yours.

Comment: Thanks your codes, but it may need adjustment. For example, you can try select text 3, and then click blank under the bottom of text 2 `This`, text 2 cannot be selected even if pointer is far away from text 3. I'm still look for a simple way to solve it. :-)

Comment: Yes... The "precision" may be improved... Making calculations for each 4 corners of an element. But you have the math principle. It is quite easy... This is middle school maths. `a^2 + b^2 = c^2` ;)